# The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#

```
public ActionResult Votation(int id=0)
{
    var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.is_active == true).FirstOrDefault();
    //query the first category
    List<CampaignManager_tbl> candidates = new List<CampaignManager_tbl>();

    candidates = (from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
                 join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl 
                 on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
                 where cat.events_info_id == events.events_info_id
                 select new CampaignManager_tbl {
                     events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                     candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                     candidates_info_id = can.candidates_info_id,
                     vote_no = cat.vote_no.Value,
                     isSelected = can.isSelected.Value,
                     events_category_id = cat.events_category_id
                 }).ToList();

    return View(candidates);
}
```

This code was working before but now I've got this error: `The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

What's wrong with this? I didn't change any of my codes before. It just this time I've got an error.

Comment: Well *where* did you get the error? Have you tried narrowing it down at all?

Comment: in this part `candidates = (from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have issue with nullable boolean there: `new CampaignManager_tbl { ... }` ? Could you try to get Count()? Does it work?

Comment: Well that's a very long query... so as I said, have you tried narrowing it down? For example, if you change your `select` to `select new { cat, can }` does that work? (The view doesn't need to work - you only need to get the call to `ToList` to work to check it...)

Comment: methinks one of `cat.vote_no`, `can.isSelected` is `null` check your db data

Comment: I know the problem now, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error because of a different problem. In my query I am selecting specific columns from an account member and its associated account:

```
DBContext.Set<AccountMember>()
    .Include(am => am.Account)
    .Select(am => new
    {
        am.ID,
        am.IsPrimary,
        Account = new { am.Account.ID, am.Account.DoNotEmail }
    });
```

Both of my boolean properties, `IsPrimary` and `DoNotEmail` are non-nullable so the resulting property type of their properties in the anonymous type is `bool`. The exception occurs when an `AccountMember` does not have an `Account`. Since `am.Account` is null, the expression `am.Account.DoNotEmail` returns null. But the anonymous type's `DoNotEmail` property inferred it was of type `bool` which cannot be set to null. The solution is to give it a hint that this should be a nullable bool by casting the property to a `bool?`:

```
DBContext.Set<AccountMember>()
    .Include(am => am.Account)
    .Select(am => new
    {
        am.ID,
        am.IsPrimary,
        Account = new { am.Account.ID, DoNotEmail = (bool?)am.Account.DoNotEmail }
    });
```

Hapily EF is smart enough to ignore this cast and not blow up trying to convert it to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I'd guess it has to do with this line:

```
 isSelected = can.isSelected.Value,
```

If when the two tables are joined, one of them does not return a value for that particular field, it will be null. It appears the type here is a `nullable` of some type - probably `bool?`, based on the naming - and that would match your error.

Try to replace it with the following:

```
isSelected = can.isSelected.HasValue ? can.isSelected.Value : false,
```

Of course, you can replace the default `false` here with `true`, if that makes more sense in your case.

**Edit:** Note that you should probably do the same for the other column you use in a similar way (I'm assuming this is returning an `int?`):

```
vote_no = cat.vote_no.HasValue ? cat.vote_no.Value : 0
```

Comment: Using EF 5 not seeing a .HasValue meth... :(

Answer (score 0):

Is `db.Candidates_Info_tbl.IsSelected` a bit field?

If so, the query could likely result in

```
isSelected = can.isSelected.Value,
```

with `isSelected` being null, whereas you probably declared `isSelected` as bool in `CampaignManager_tbl` class.

Change the `isSelected` to bool in the `CampaignManager_tbl` class and try again.

Answer (score 0):

if your field type is int while some value is null, then you can use case-when and convert to bit like below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FieldName IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(BIT,FieldName) ELSE CONVERT(BIT,0)  END AS NewFieldName
```